# Passing QString in a slot

Tags: c++, qt

I have a working signal slot mechanism for the user checking and unchecking a checkbox.

```
QWidget *w = new QWidget(this);
w->setFixedSize(300,200);
QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;

foreach(QString filt, filters){
    QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox(filt, this);
    checkbox->setChecked(true);
    vbox->addWidget(checkbox);

    connect(checkbox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(cbstate(int)));

}

w->setLayout(vbox);
w->show();

void MainWindow::cbstate(int state){
    if(state == 0){
        //unchecked
        QMessageBox::information(this, "blah", "You have unchecked this box");
    }
    else if (state == 2){
        //checked
        QMessageBox::information(this, "blah", "You have checked this box");
    }
}
```

The explanation of my problem is quite simple, I need to pass the `QString filt` to the `cbstate` function.

I have no idea how to do this? When I've attempted to add it to the slot, it's throwing errors.

Comment: You can't do it, since the cbstate function is slot and its signal is stateChanged(int) which accepts parameter of type int only.

Comment: Ahhh ok, so is there an explainable way that I can alter things to pass it in somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `cbstate` slot you can get `filt` by using `QObject::sender()`. It will return pointer to `checkbox`. You can get `filt` from it.

```
void MainWindow::cbstate(int state){
    QChecBox* checkBox = qobject_cast<QCheckBox*>(sender());
    QString filt = checkBox->text();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I know want to do some extra reading to understand what you just provided me with there. Am I looking into QObject?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Qt's [QSignalMapper](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qsignalmapper.html) class, which would in my opinion be the cleaner option to using `QObject::sender()`. The documentation is quite thorough.

Comment: +1. This is the proper, explicit, non-misbehaving way of knowing the emitter of a signal.